# How to define an array with n number of elements inside of a class

Tags: c++, arrays, class

I've been making a program in C++ that calculates the surface area of a polygon with a shoelace method. I've already checked in the main code and that part works fine. The problem appears when I try to put that same code into a class.
This is the code for a header file:

```
#include "Tacka.h"
class mnogougao{
public:
    Tacka* x;
    mnogougao(int n);
    float pertlanje(int n);
}
```

This is the code for the cpp file for the class

```
#include "tacka.h"
#include "tackaa.cpp"
#include "mnogougao.h"
mnogougao::mnogougao(int n){
    
    x = new Tacka [n];
}

float mnogougao::pertlanje( int n){

    int j=n-1;
    float povrsina=0.0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        
        povrsina+=(x[i].getx()+x[j].getx())*(x[j].gety()-x[i].gety());
        j=i;
        
    }
    if(povrsina<0) povrsina*=-1;
    povrsina/=2.0;

    return povrsina;
}
```

And this is the main code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Tacka.h"
#include "mnogougao.h"
#include "mnogougao.cpp"
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"Insert number of points of a polygon:"<<endl;
    int n;
    cin>>n;
    mnogougao x(n);

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){ 
        cout<<"Insert coordinates of "<<i+1<<". point of the polygon:"<<endl;
        float a;
        cout<<"X:";
        cin>>a;
        float b;
        cout<<"Y:";
        cin>>b;
        x.x[i].setx(a);
        x.x[i].sety(b);
    }
    cout<<"Surface area of a polygon is: "<<x.pertlanje(n)<<endl;
system("pause");
}
```

Also, I forgot to add, this is the code for the header file for Tacka class

```
#pragma once

class Tacka
{
public:
float x,y; 
float getx();
float gety();
void setx(float a);
void sety(float a);
Tacka();
Tacka(float a, float b);
};
```

And this is the code for the cpp file for Tacka class

```
#include "tacka.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
Tacka::Tacka(){
x=0.0;
y=0.0;
}
Tacka::Tacka(float a, float b)
{
x=a;
y=b;
}
float Tacka::getx(){
return x;
}
float Tacka::gety(){
return y;
}
void Tacka::setx(float a){
x=a;
}
void Tacka::sety(float a){
y=a;
}
```

It says that I have made an error in the constructor in a cpp file:error C2533: 'mnogougao::{ctor}' : constructors not allowed a return type. Can someone please explain to me what mistake have I made? I'm pretty sure the mistake is somewhere in declaring a number of elements in an array, but I wasn't able to find anything that could help me solve the issue.

Comment: `mnogougao x();` -- What is this line intended to do?

Comment: Use `std::vector<Tacka> x;` instead and in the constructor `mnogougao(int n) : x(n) {}`

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it's a constructor inside of my main code. I've realized I forgot to copy it properly, so I've added n inside of the brackets.

Comment: Red flags that may or may not be related: `#include "tacka.cpp"`, `#include "mnogougao.cpp"`. Without knowing the exact error message, it's also hard to diagnose this, but I _suspect_ there may be an error in your `tacka` constructor.

Comment: You should never include a cpp file.

Comment: @KatarinaBrkljač -- Before you edited the code, `mnogougao x();` is not a constructor call.  It is a function declaration -- the function name is `x`, it takes no arguments, and returns a `mnogougao`.  This is why you should make sure you're posting the actual code you are compiling and running, and not hastily typed in code that looks like your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of the class definition.

This will trigger the error

```
error C2533: 'mnogougao::{ctor}': constructors not allowed a return type
```

in MSVC (Visual Studio).

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/658Px4EMz)

Comment: That was the mistake. Thank you for helping me!